# Campaign code not being sent from Branch.io from Facebook App Install campaign

Tags: ios, facebook, branch.io

Currently we have set up branch.io and our app to receive and record a "campaign code" from a deeplink.

We now want to use these deeplinks in a facebook app install campaign.

After using these deeplinks in our facebook app install ads, we are no longer receiving the "campaign codes" in our app.

There is paragraph in the branch.io documentation noting that the facebook sdk could be intercepting this data.
https://dev.branch.io/features/facebook-ads/support/ios/#intercepting-deep-links-before-branch

However, our app does not have reference to the `fetchDeferredAppLinkData(Context, CompletionHandler)` method.

Comment: Alex from Branch.io here: are you receiving ANY deep link parameters back from Branch, or is it just the campaign param that is missing?

Comment: Hi Alex, first to answer your question. We receive the following parameters back from Branch with the set up mentioned above. 
`{
   "+clicked_branch_link" = 0;
   "+is_first_session" = 0;
}`

Comment: Also, to make sure that the branch link is working, we tried using the branch link without facebook and we get the following results: '{
   "$marketing_title" = BranchTest;
   "$one_time_use" = 0;
   "+click_timestamp" = 1484088925;
   "+clicked_branch_link" = 1;
   "+is_first_session" = 0;
   "+match_guaranteed" = 1;
   "~campaign" = BranchTest;
   "~channel" = BranchTest;
   "~creation_source" = 1;
   "~feature" = marketing;
   "~id" = 347500925801618525;
   "~marketing" = 1;
   "~referring_link" = "xxx";
}'

Comment: That does sound the like the same issue you linked to in that docs page (Facebook intercepting the link data). Could you submit a ticket to our [Integrations team](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) so we can debug further?

Comment: We have submitted a ticket. hope to hear from your team soon!

Comment: @AlexBauer One additional bit of info. When we use the Facebook Ad Manager to send a preview of an ad (with the branch link) to our feed, the branch link works and we receive all the same parameters from the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

To help anyone who may come upon this question, the issue here turned out to be an invalid image URL entry ($og_image_url) specified for the link. This was identified by using Facebook's Sharing Debugger (here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/).